# Including an article if the following phrase already contains it

Tags: articles, definite-articles

For example, when referencing a webpage:

> Visit the "The Performers" page to learn about our musical lineup.

In this case, I want to tell someone to visit a webpage entitled "The Performers" to find more information, but the repetition is throwing me off.

If I were to remove the first "the" before "The Performers," though, then it would essentially read as "Visit page" without an article.

So, is it okay to use the article of the webpage title as the article for the sentence, or must I include the first "the" before the webpage title? The two iterations:

> Visit the "The Performers" page to learn about our musical lineup.
>
> Visit "The Performers" page to learn about our musical lineup.

Comment: There are different opinions about how to deal with this issue, described in many style guides. What did your research into it reveal?

Comment: Easily rearranged: Visit the page "The Performers" to learn ...

Comment: @yosefbaskin unfortunately, it can’t be rearranged in the asset!

Answer (score -1):

Technically, if you are putting a "the" between the quotation marks, it is part of the page name, so you can have 2 "the" next to each other because one is a name and the other serves its article functions, which is needed and necessary. Therefore do the first iteration:

> Visit the "The Performers" page to learn about our musical lineup.

The repetition might sound off, but you could adjust the name. Looking through some answers [in this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59750/when-can-the-be-used-before-a-name#:%7E:text=If%20the%20name%20or%20proper,stone%20was%20called%20the%20Excalibur.), we can see that the first "the" cannot be removed. The second one is optional.